# Apache wicket: how to update form explicitly?

Tags: java, validation, wicket

I have an issue with ListView and validation on page.

I have ListView, and underneath it I have TextField, where the user can enter values. I have "publish" and "draft save" buttons on my page. Publish is a button, where popup (ModalWindow) is shown, where user should confirm entered data. Save draft is saving without confirmation. Both are SecuredAjaxLink objects.

When a user enters data in TextField, it is saved in ListView, but the whole list isn't updated as user should press button Add below. This is ok.

The problem is, that I have business validation, where user entered information is checked for some rules. When validation failing all fields (containing wrong info) are highlighted with css. To explicitly add value from TextField to ListView i'm doing

```
target.addComponent(form);
```

This is performed before data goes to validation. So all fields are updated. This works fine for publish button (with confirmation ModalWindow), but doesn't work with the link without popup. As I understand there is something wrong with lifecycle of target, but I'm stuck with it.

Maybe someone had something similar or know the answer?

How can I update the page without using popup?

Here is the code:
Draft link:

```
add(new SecuredAjaxSubmitLink(LinkNames.savelaterLink.toString(), form,
                RoleController.CONTROLLER.getAccessController()) {
            @Override
            public void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
                target.addComponent(form);
                insert(appl, false, form, target, new MainMenu(getString("accept.application.draft.success.message")), trail, checkbox);
            }
```

Publish link:

```
add(new CustomAjaxSubmitLink(LinkNames.submitLink.toString(), form,
                RoleController.CONTROLLER.getAccessController()) {
            @Override
            protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form form) {
                target.addComponent(form);
                publishPopup.show(target);
            }
        });

publishPopup.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback() {
            public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                if (ApplicationInsertActionPanel.this.getSelectedAction() != null
                        && ApplicationInsertActionPanel.this.getSelectedAction().equals(Action.CONFIRM)) {
                    insert(appl,
                            true,
                            form,
                            target,
                            new MainMenu(ApplicationInsertActionPanel.this
                                    .getString("accept.application.publish.success.message")), trail, checkbox);
                }

            }
        });
```

I've added

```
@Override
            protected void onError(final AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
            {
                super.onError(target, form);
                target.addComponent(form);
```

to my draft link, but still page is not fully updated. 
I suppose it is because target's lifecycle is not ended, like it is ending when i'm using popup window. Popup window is opening "new page" and old target can be updated, but when i'm not using popup, the page stays like it was. 
So now i'm thinking about some workaround to end target lifecycle. I was thinking about transparent popup window without any functionality, but is really very dirty solution.

Any ideas? Thanks!
                }

Answer (score 0):

My english isnt so well, and i dont totally understand you Post. 
is it:
type word in Textfield --> one of those submit buttons
--> word appears on listview?
if you want to Validate the input why dont you use a class that inherits from `IValidator.class`

and if you want to update your form you can add a updatebehaviour to your form

```
final AjaxFormSubmitBehavior            formbehavior    = new AjaxFormSubmitBehavior("onChange") {
    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget arg0) {
        arg0.add(getForm());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget arg0) {
        arg0.add(getForm());
    }
};
```

then you can add this behaviour to your form or extend it to your needs

```
form.add(formbehavior)
```

i dont know if your problem is somehow related to my answer, but i suppose that you wanted to know how to update your form without loading the page new.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was trying to implement something similar (with behaviors), but i've failed. There is such logic:
type word in TextField -> word is added to ListView, but it isn't updated, if user wants, to add new, he must press button ADD below ListView. And the last element, that stays in TextField is added in ListView. -> User press buttons save draft/publish -> model object is sent to business logic for validation -> logic failed and with publish page is updated and listview fully updated, but with draft link - isn't. List updated, but not highlighted with validation (last elem)

Comment: your samplecode is more irritating than helping, show pls the code of the Textfield the ListView too, their models and maybe their behaviours and those links. and if i understood it, your problem is with the draft link (why no button?) that after validation the list ist not highlighted on error. So how should the list be highlighted? with red color? and did you tried to write yur own Validator? maybe you can make a screenshot of what you mean so ppl can imagine, what you want.